# Devise how to pass current_user to confirm_instructions mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have Devise set up and woking great. I am using confirmable and have modified this as per their 2 step registration process guide:

[set password at confirmation](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation)

I have one last requirement that I am having trouble with.

What we have is a 2 scenarios

1) a user can register as new

2) A logged in user (current_user) can create a new user. 
When a logged in user creates a new user I want to be able to add their email into the confirmation email sent to the new created user

In the email to the new registered user I need to pass in the current_user.email somehow if the user was created by a user one logged in. I will then do a simple if check and add some extra text to the email.

the confirmation_instructions.html.erb currently:

```
<p>Welcome <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

What I need is something like

```
<p>Welcome <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<% if !@user.email.nil? %>
   <p> some additional welcome text here from <%= @user.email %> </p>
<% end %>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token) %></p>
```

I have been going back and forth with custom mailer with no joy.
Can someone help me out, I am sure there is something simple I am missing here.

For info (I know this is not the best method but we are throwing together a very quick app for demo purposes) a user creates a new contact by typing in am email address. If the email address does not exist in the user table a new user is created then the contact relationship created (snippet of the controller):

```
class DashboardController < ApplicationController
     before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def show
    @contacts = current_user.contacts
  end

  def createcontact
    user2 = User.find_by_email(params[:contact_email])
    if user2.nil?
            newContact = User.create(:email => params[:contact_email])
            if newContact.save
                 current_user.newUserContact(newContact)
                 redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => "conact has been saved as well as a new contact"
            else
                redirect_to dashboard_path, :notice => "ERROR saving contact"
            end
    else
      .
      .
      .
      .
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Follow this tutorial](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Use-custom-mailer) for setting up a custom mailer.

In config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.mailer = "UserMailer".
```

Create a new mailer that inherits from Devise's mailer in the folder app/mailers:

```
# user_mailer.rb
class UserMailer < Devise::Mailer

  def invite(sender, recipient)
    @sender = sender
    @recipient = recipient

    mail( :to => recipient.email,
          :subject => "Invite by #{sender.name}"
        )
  end
end
```

Now, move your devise mailer views to the folder app/views/user_mailer. There create a new email view where you can use the variables @sender and @recipient.

```
# invite.html.erb
<p>Welcome <%= @recipient.email %>!</p>

<% if @sender.email? %>
  <p> some additional welcome text here from <%= @sender.email %> </p>
<% end %>
```

Now, in your controller, you can call the following:

```
UserMailer.invite(current_user, newContact).deliver
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply. What we have is a 2 scenarios  1) a user can register as new 2) another user (current_user) can create a new user. When a logged in user creates a new user I want to be able to add their email into the confirmation email sent to the new user.

Comment: Edited the question to clear up any confusion of what I have asked

Comment: How is a logged in user creating a new user? Can you provide that controller code?

Comment: Cool, I did originally try using custom mailer but adding to the Devise method then using super not make a new one. I will give this a go now. Thanks for your time looking over this.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I just need to stop send 2 mails now, skip confirmation is no good since I am doing 2 step registration, email then set password on confirm and since skip_confirmation sets the :confirmed_at to current time date I need to override this. Thanks for your help on this, much appreciated